# trigger after insert oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I have 2 tables and I want to trigger data from the first to the second after I do some inserts into the first table.

**PERSON**

```
PERSONID   NOT NULL NUMBER(10)   
USERNAME   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50) 
PASSWORD   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50) 
FIRSTNAME  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50) 
LASTNAME   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50) 
EMAIL      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50) 
BIRTHDATE           DATE         
USERTYPE   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20) 
BIRTHPLACE          VARCHAR2(50)
```

**USERNAMES**

```
ID       NOT NULL NUMBER(10)   
USERNAME NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50) 
PASSWORD NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50) 
EMAIL    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
```

`PersonID` in `PERSON` table is a FK for `ID` in `USERNAMES` table.I want to make some inserts(big data in `PERSON` table - about 500000 entries) and I want all 500000 to be triggered into `ID`, `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD` and `EMAIL` in the `USERNAMES` table.

I tried this trigger but if fails after the second `INSERT` in `PERSON` table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_person
AFTER INSERT
   ON Person


    DECLARE
       v_id NUMBER(10);
       v_username varchar2(50);  
       v_password varchar2(50);
       v_email varchar2(50);
    BEGIN

       -- Find username of person 
       SELECT PersonId,Username,Password,Email INTO v_id,v_username,v_password,v_email
       FROM Person;

       -- Insert record into USERNAMES table
       INSERT INTO Usernames
       ( 
        Id,
        Username,
        Password,
        Email
       )
       VALUES
       ( v_id,
         v_username,
         v_password,
         v_email
       );

    END;
```

The first insert is working but,
I get the following error after the second insert into `PERSON` table:

```
Error starting at line 3 in command:
insert into person values(1,'SparhatC','qwezx2','Cosmin','Sparhat','cos.cosm@asd.com',TO_DATE('1990/07/09', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),'2','Botosani')
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.INSERT_PERSON", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.INSERT_PERSON'
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested
```

Can you please advise something about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your trigger body, you're selecting ALL records from the PERSON table. This is the reason for your error - when the trigger fires for the second time, PERSON contains two rows, but `SELECT INTO` must only return one row.

In fact, the `SELECT` is superfluous - if you change your statement-level trigger to a row-level trigger by adding the `FOR EACH ROW` clause, you can simply reference the new values using `:NEW`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_person
AFTER INSERT
   ON Person
FOR EACH ROW    
    BEGIN
       -- Insert record into audit table
       INSERT INTO Usernames
       ( 
        Id,
        Username,
        Password,
        Email
       )
       VALUES
       ( :NEW.PersonID,
         :NEW.Username,
         :NEW.Password,
         :NEW.Email
       );

    END;
```

Comment: Cool.I understand now.Very quick answer.It works.10x

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer solved your problem, please consider clicking the checkbox to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The select return more than one row.

So you must have a unique column into your query and then it will returns only one.

Try to use 'where' cause you take all the table rows with this.